# PRAW: get_me() doesn't work even though I'm logged in?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I have a Reddit bot written in Python + PRAW that logs in using a username/password pair (i.e. not using OAuth), like so:

```
reddit.login(username, password)
```

This has worked fine for everything I've done so far, but when I just went to implement parsing the bot's own comments to see if any should be deleted, I ran into a problem. I'm calling `reddit.get_me()` to get the currently logged in user, but no matter what I do, it always throws this:

> ```
> OAuthScopeRequired: `get_me` requires the OAuth2 scope identity
> ```

There obviously shouldn't be any access issues given that I *am* logged in as the user, so I shouldn't have to request any special permissions do do something as trivial as retrieving the currently logged in user. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I seem to have solved it by just directly calling `praw.objects.LoggedInRedditor(reddit, user_name=username)` instead of getting it from `get_me()`.

Not sure why this functionality was duplicated like this in the first place, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `r.user` to get an instance of the currently logged in `Redditor`. To fetch the comments: `r.user.get_comments()`.

Also, simpler than your proposed solution to fetch an arbitrary `Redditor` instance is the `r.get_redditor(username)` function.